# Angular copy creating a duplicate entry in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list

I have a select drop down on the page. Suppose it has 3 items, orange, banana, mango. There is a button to add a new item to the list. Consider orange is selected on the drop down currently, and when I click on the add new button and try to add a new fruit item say peach what i see is peach is repeated twice. The existing selected Orange is now replaced with peach as well. I am using `Angular.copy` as given below, why is this being repeated ? The list of fruit is coming from the server I have a fruits arraylist in my action and parsed as json to display on the page.

```
<select id="fruitSelect" ng-options="fruit.description for fruit in fruits" ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-change="fruitsClicked()"> </select>
```

And I have a button, on click of this button a modal is opened and asks user to give a name to save fruit to the list.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="saveFruit()">Save</button>
```

The JS controller code:

```
$scope.saveFruit= function() {
        var length = $scope.fruits.push({
          description: angular.copy($scope.form.newFruit)
         });
      $scope.selectedFruit= angular.copy($scope.fruits[length-1]);
    };
```

I want to select the newly added fruit in the drop down, so for `ng-model` `selectedFruit` I am setting it to the angular copy value of the last fruit in the saved search. This works fine, but it creates a duplicate. It replaces orange which was previously selected with peach in my case.

Comment: Create demo that replicates this. We can't see `$scope.form`. Also not clear why you use copy twice and don't just create copy object once and make that equal to `selectedFruit`. Also not clear what relationship is between `savedSearches` and `fruits` arrays

Comment: sorry that was a copy/paste error. Changed it to fruits. I will try to create a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16234/) that I believe have the answer.

You don't need to use `angular.copy` on this case. This function is used mainly to copy objects that javascript would otherwise only copy the pointer.

From what you provided I guess you might be calling the function to add the fruit to your array twice, e.g. `ng-submit` on the form and `ng-click` in the submit button of the same form.

Update:

Updated the JSfiddle.
When changing the selected option you just need to pass to the `ng-model` which index of your array will be the selected.

Comment: Thanks for the JSfiddle. For example orange is selected in drop-down and when i add peach and click on don't add duplicate, peach will get added to the drop down, and i also want peach to be displayed/selected in drop down as well. How to do that?

Comment: @MaverickAzy Updated the answer with a new fiddle, please check it out.

Comment: does make sense using copy if plan on use form object again to pass new item to array